# How to display featured products on home page using Zerif Lite on Wordpress with WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, product, wordpress-featured-image

So I set up an e-store using Zerif Lite's Bootstrap theme. I'm struggling with trying to add featured products on first page. I've tried to use different plugins but they don't work, so perhaps there's a specific PHP code for that?

So far I've managed to make 1 featured product in Latest News section as a pictured thumbnail, while latest news contains redirect JavaScript code, which redirects to the product page.

I'd like to have several product pictures that have embedded link to each of the products. Hope you can help!

Edit: (Code added)

```
<div class="latestnews-img"> 
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?> 
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
    <?php else: ?> <img src="example.com/mypic.jpg">; 
    <?php endif; ?> 
  </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to add some code as to what you have tried, since this is very broad at the moment

Comment: <div class="latestnews-img">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

           
            
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
           <?php else: ?>

            <img src="http://example.com/mypic.jpg"> 

           <?php endif; ?>

          </a>
         </div>

Comment: This modification was made to latest_news.php

Comment: You can modify your question to add code, it looks better that way. I did it for you this time :).

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question, I think this line is the culprit:

```
<?php else: ?> <img src="example.com/mypic.jpg">;
```

You don't have the semicolon in a php tag, so this could be causing issues.

Comment: No, it's not the line. The line works perfectly. Let me give you an example: When I try adding other featured products by creating another post, which show's at as a latest post on the home page, it automatically gives the thumbnail image of that post the same exact image as in the other post.

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me. You are hardcoding an image link, so how would you expect the image to change?

Comment: We'll not exactly. I'd just like to hear someones solution, how to put different featured images as links to different products. I'm actually beginner with coding, so I'd appreciate if you could use simple terminology.

Comment: I understand that the theme I'm using is not really meant for e-commerce, but my team mates really like the theme setup, so I have no choice but to find out a way of how to add another segment to the homepage that would show different featured images without crashing the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not experienced with coding with WP I'd recommend looking at the [shortcodes that are included with WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6) - there's one specifically for displaying featured images. That's probably your quickest and easiest solution.

Comment: Unfortunately shortcode doesn't apply in this case, since I'm using the default front page as the home page, so I can't access the page content from the "All pages" section in the back end.

Comment: You can use a shortcode outside of the page content with the [do_shortcode()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function. Insert it in your themes `front-page.php` template if it as one, or create one if it doesn't.

Comment: I Tried this: I placed this function to of the front-page.php                            **<?php echo do_shortcode('[featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]'); ?>**            It didn't show the right result, no matter in which part of the front-page.php I inserted it. Sometimes it gave me _"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'_ in the directory of the selected theme. Thanks for the tip though, but could you explain, in which part of the front-page.php it needs to be inserted and if the code I stated above is correct.